# Is there a summary of visual studio 2008 runtime versions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, runtime

I've been looking into a strange problem where loading of one of our application's dlls fails on certain systems (using the Global Flags loader snap flag shows it's somewhere within LoadLibraryEx).  The logs in windbg show that there seem to be several different versions of `MSVCR90.DLL` being referenced.  It appears that the version referenced in our manifest is different to the redistributable runtime we're installing.

I've been trying to find a definitive list of the different runtime versions for the Visual Studio service packs and security hotfixes, but I can't find anything useful.

On my own machine I have at least five different ones installed, but I can't relate them to what Visual Studio is building.  This is what I've found up to now:

- 9.0.21022.8 - this is what my VS2008 SP1 machine appears to be building against
- 9.0.21022.218: Security update for VS2008
- 9.0.30729  ?
- 9.0.30729.17 - VS2008 SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?FamilyID=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2
- 9.0.30729.4148 - VS2008 SP1 28/7/2009 (also seems to include the ATL update) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973552 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971092/
- 9.0.30729.4974 - seems to be part of Team Foundation Server 2010
- 9.0.30729.5570 - 21 April 2011 security update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2465361

Is there a more complete list than this, or one that clarifies which version we are building?

What is a fully-patched Visual Studio 2008 installation?  SP1 + ATL hotfix?  Are there further security updates?

EDIT: 
I've found this page which does at least put all the downloads in one place: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;2019667&sd=rss&spid=12913

EDIT2: 
It appears that merely updating to the most recent visual studio libraries doesn't automatically use them -- you need to [explicitly bind](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2008/10/29/binding-to-the-most-recent-visual-studio-libraries/) to the latest library version

Comment: I think more generally 4974 is from VS2010, not just TFS - it's in WCU\VC90SP1 on the DVD. I've got another one 4418 (as well as 4148) [from the VS2010 RC](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/08/vs-2010-net-4-release-candidate.aspx#7342999)

Comment: Also: 9.0.30729.6161 - 14 Jun 2011 Security Update, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538243

Answer (score 2):

Run Microsoft Update (not Windows update) and it'll patch you up to the very latest version. There are a few of them (5 or 6 IIRC).

Comment: Thanks - I've just noticed that a new update is available via update, 9.0.30729.5570.  On Win7 Microsoft Update and Windows Update are one and the same (I think)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but for the benefit of future readers, I have one here: http://niemiro.co.uk/Blog/windows-update-troubleshooting/visual-c-file-versions/

It isn't totally complete yet, but it has more than what is currently posted in this thread, and I haven't yet found a better list.

If you have anything to add, a comment here would be greatly appreciated, and I will add it when I get the chance.

Comment: If you still have that list somewhere, please put it inside the answer; without it the answer is somewhat useless ;)