# Is it compatible for VC redistributed package 2005, 2008, 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

what does the  redistributed package contains? Can 2`005, 2008, 2010` redistributed packages coexist on the same system?

Answer (score 1):

The redistributable packages contain the C++ runtime routines for each version of Visual Studio. They can coexist as the Windows Side-by-Side (SxS) support takes care of that, which means that you can have many versions of (say) VS2008 runtimes.  See the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816610/is-there-a-summary-of-visual-studio-2008-runtime-versions) for a summary of some of the different versions.

Comment: Note that Side-by-Side is only used for different releases of the same major version; different major versions continue to be differentiated by filename.  And VC++2010 does not use SxS any longer.

Comment: if no SxS supports, how to ensure 2010 can coxist with 2008?

Comment: also, when we patch 2008, will it be two versions for the same dll.

Comment: Between major versions of visual studio the runtime libraries have different names, eg MSVCRP90.dll for VS2008 (= version 9.0), MSVCRP80.dll for VS2005 (= version 8.0).  If you update VS2008 to VS2008SP1 then there's a different set of runtime dlls but with the same names.  However when you build your application the information about the runtimes that it needs are stored in the Manifest, and Windows takes care of pulling out the right versions for you using SxS.